# How to implement Bottom Sheet, where components above depends of the size and motion this Bottom Sheet?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, material-design, bottom-sheet

I need to implement this UI.
[image: Closed Bottom Sheet]
This is `layout` with a closed `Bottom Sheet`.

[image: Open Bottom Sheet]
This is `layout` with an open `Bottom Sheet`.

I implemented `Bottom Sheet` as in the design, but my problem is that the `Bottom Sheet` climbs over the `Recycler View`. I want to implement this like in design - when I open the `Bottom Sheet`, my `Recycler View` will decreased dynamically in size. Please tell me how to set this behavior for `Bottom Sheet`. How can I get distance between `Toolbar` and top part of `Bottom Sheet` and how I can reduce `Recycler View` size with animation when `Bottom Sheet` was opened?